# How do I recover deleted files from rare filetypes?

Tags: file-recovery

Recuva recovers the jpg's, the pdf's, and the common filetypes.

But what about, say, sqlite files? Or other types of random files?

I'm trying to recover lost files from a USB drive that the computer can't recognize anymore. Recuva has recovered many of the jpg's and pdf's.

Comment: I don't know Rucuva but, you may need to ask them directly. However, a file is a file, there is nothing special about the file type you mention and as such, should be retrievable if the file still exists. Unless Recuva only looks for jpg's and pdf's that is... May be a Google search for some other recovery software may yield an answer.

Answer (score 1):

let me refurbrish your ideas about data recovery in recuva.

Windows has an index that keeps an entry of all the files in every folder of the
disk.(in something called the Master File Table (MFT).
When you delete a file in windows all it does is to erase the entry from the
index - not the hard drive. The contents of the file are still there, but you
can't access it.

When a file has an index entry ,
Windows makes sure not to overwrite the space on the hard drive where the file
lives. Once you delete the file, however, Windows is free to use that 'blank
space' for other files.

If only you could recreate that index entry so you could get at the file! That's
what Recuva does.

that said , recuva is not limited to a few file types but it makes it easier to
filter for results based on file name/type.Hower it is limited to a few file
systems -
FAT12, FAT16, FAT32, exFAT, NTFS, NTFS5 , NTFS + EFS.

you may read more about this in their
documentation which can be found [here](http://www.piriform.com/docs/recuva).

these are some of the software that are best of it's kind.
[Undelete Plus](http://undelete-plus.com/),[FileSalvage](http://subrosasoft.com/software/filesalvage)(It claims to recover
virtually any type of file on multiple partition types ( for MAC),[Data Rescue for Mac](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php)
and [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

If you are very much concerned about your lost data feel free to call professionals.

Answer (score 0):

did not use Recuva for rare filetypes, but as I know at least [Restoration](http://download.cnet.com/Restoration/3000-2094_4-10322950.html) recovered all files I had on my drive. Little bit older utility but still works. Just try it it is free.